Prevent authorize attribute from redirecting to access denied path
I quite despise redirecting to status code pages, I think if there's an error on a certain URL, the response should be returned to THAT URL. However ASP.NET redirects 403 responses to /Account/AccessDenied. Is there a way to hook into the callback and return a view without redirecting?
So for exmaple if the user navigates to /admin which requires the Administrator role but they don't have it, the server will return my custom view without redirecting.

After trying all the possible code i found there is no way to restrict the redirect to the access denied page but as workaround you could write the custom response for:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MyCookieAuth")
     .AddCookie("MyCookieAuth", options =>
     {
         options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
         
         options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
         {
             OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
             {
                 // Prevent redirection when access is denied
                 context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
                 return context.Response.WriteAsync("Access Denied: You do not have permission to access this resource.");
             }
         };
     });



@iKingNinja so in my opinion there is no issue if you use redirect with access denied page and it is the default approach

Sorry i mixed up questions , your answer is definitely correct.

@iKingNinja n problem . glad it helped you
